# Setting JScrollPane visible/invisible via JCheckBox not working

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, visibility, jcheckbox

There is a JCheckBox called "**one**" and another called "**two**". There is also a JScrollPane called "**sp**". In it is a JTextArea. The point of the checkboxes is to hide and show certain parts of the program. I simplified the program and here I tediously explain what is supposed to happen just to make sure you understand the program.

This is supposed to happen:

Initially only **one** is visible and it is unselected. Whenever **one** is selected, **two** should be set visible. Whenever **two** is selected, **sp** should be set visible. When a checkbox is unselected, the corresponding component is set invisible. However, when one is unselected, **sp** is also set invisible. (**one** controlls **two** and **sp**).

The problem:

When **one** is selected, **two** is visible. But when **two** is selected, **sp** is not visible (it should be). When one is unselected while **two** is selected, **two** is invisible (this should happen). But when **one** is selected, **two** is visible and all of a sudden **sp** is now visible. After this point, the program functions as it was intended.

This however works with other JComponents (in replace of the JScrollPane).

What could be wrong?

```
package tests;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Checkboxscrollpane extends JPanel {

    private JCheckBox one, two;
    private JScrollPane sp;

    private Checkboxscrollpane() {
        Listener listener = new Listener();

        one = new JCheckBox();
        one.addActionListener(listener);
        add(one);

        two = new JCheckBox();
        two.addActionListener(listener);
        add(two);

        sp = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea("hello"));
        add(sp);

        one.setVisible(true);
        two.setVisible(false);
        sp.setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        one.setLocation(50, 50);
        two.setLocation(70, 70);
        sp.setLocation(90, 90);
    }

    private class Listener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == one) {
                two.setVisible(one.isSelected());
            }
            sp.setVisible(one.isSelected() && two.isSelected());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.add(new Checkboxscrollpane());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should revalidate the `Checkboxscrollpane` panel.

But you shouldn't set location of components on every paint event:

```
setLayout(null);

    one.setSize(100, 20);
    two.setSize(100, 20);
    sp.setSize(100, 20);
    one.setLocation(50, 50);
    two.setLocation(70, 70);
    sp.setLocation(90, 90);
```

And remove the `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {` method.

Comment: I do it like I did because I want my components in certain locations. Doing what you said locates the components using the default panel layout which is what I do not want.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add line: `setLayout(null)`